# Symfony first-steps problems

Tags: php, symfony

I'm newbie in Symfony and I'm following a tutorial. The first excercise is very simple, but I don't know why is not working.

In my source folder I first tried with these lines:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class GenusController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/genus")
     */

    public function showAction()
    {
        return new Response('Test ');

    }

}
```

I tried in in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8888/my_project/web/genus
```

And it works. But then if I add new lines:

```
class GenusController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/genus/{genusName}")
     */

    public function showAction($genusName)
    {
        return new Response('The genus: '.$genusName);

    }

}
```

and tested it:

```
http://localhost:8888/my_project/web/genus/test
```

My browser displays:

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

What is missing?
Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How to you start your application, `php bin/console server:start`? If you do, the proper url should be: `http://localhost:8888/genus/something`

Comment: Have you tried to access from your dev environment ?

    http://localhost:8888/my_project/web/app_dev.php/genus/test

otherwise, try to clear your cache.

Comment: I didn't start my application through php bin/console server:start. I'm using MAMP and I thought that I didn't have to do something else

Comment: @fliim I just tried and I got the error No route found for "GET /genus/test", By the way, in the tutorial they recommended to mark the "src" folder as Sources Root, does that impact somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In `prod` environment: the **configuration information** is cached and not automatically refreshed.
It means:

- @nnotation in php files are cached
- .yml file  are cached
- .xml file  are cached
- *.twig file are cached

The error you are having is the new route you've created is not cached and not accessible to prod environment.

It means you either have to call `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` everytime or you have to use the `dev` environnement which is far better when developping. It provides better error message for 404 and 500 errors too.

It means you have to use the `app_dev.php` instead of `app.php`.
You can try

```
http://localhost:8888/app_dev.php/my_project/web/genus/test
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got the error: Not Found
The requested URL /app_dev.php/my_project/web/genus/test was not found on this server. By the way, in the tutorial they recommended to mark the "src" folder as Sources Root, does that impact somehow?

Comment: can you do `php app/console debug:router ` and see if you have the route you want in it? Marking the "src" folder as Sources Root is a Phpstorm functionality isn't it? The IDE is not related to symfony

Comment: I tried the command php app/console debug:router but didnt work, then I tried with php bin/console debug:router. And yes, I can see the route app_genus_show             ANY      ANY      ANY    /genus/{genusName}

Comment: If you are using `bin/console` you are using symfony 3 not symfony 2!

Comment: I used that command because I saw it on the tutorial. I checked the version (symfony -v) and I have Symfony Installer (1.5.9) and I got this info  To create a new project called blog in the current directory using the latest stable version of Symfony, execute the following command:
symfony new blog, and more options like  symfony new blog lts, symfony new blog 2.8 or symfony new blog 3.0, symfony new blog 2.8.1 or symfony new blog 3.0.1, symfony demo. How could I know that I did a complete installation?

Comment: what is the version inside composer.json for symfony? To check a complete installation run composer install

Comment: require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*", (is this what you mean?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133458/discussion-between-goto-and-andreahg).

Comment: BTW, I didn't mention that I'm using MAMP, do I need to run the command php bin/console server:run anyways?